# SPARQL: Get distinct namespaces of a result set

Tags: sparql, rdf

I'm trying to get the distinct namespaces of a set of results. For example, I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?instance
WHERE {
    ?entity a :entity .
    ?entity a :startPoint .
    ?instance a ?entity .
    }
}
```

This query return a huge list of results like

```
http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2018/1#100019
http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2018/1#100034251
http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2018/1#100034726
http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2018/1#100034748
....
http://nextprot.org/rdf/gene/ENSG00000164588
```

I need to get the distinct namespaces of the set. Here:

```
http://nextprot.org/rdf/gene/
http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2018/1#
```

I can get this by post-processing the result of my query, but since it can return billions of results, I'd like to get this in pure SPARQL. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: those are not called prefixes but namespaces. And you would need to apply some string functions of SPARQL and hope it's enough. you can try replace with a regex. Or better, if the triple store of your choice provides some custom function thing become easier

Comment: Take care that Regex can be really heavy.

Comment: I'm gonna try a regexp and see if it takes lot of time.